# Android ListView with Images inside of ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

I have been trying to get a listview inside of SherlockListFragment for about a week (total of like 12 hours) and I can't figure it out. I'm out of options here. So, I have three tabs, which all need to have listviews, with images. I managed to get the listviews working, but I just cannot seem to find a way to add images. I am a HUGE beginner at this as well.

Here is one of the three tab classes that extend SherlockListFragment:

```
@Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] commands  = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currentmobs_selections);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.main_list_item, commands);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
```

Now I did make a custom array for the listview in attempt to get it working, but I didn't even know how to implement the custom array adapter into the code. If anyone knows any way to get a image/text listview inside of a ListFragment I'd be soooo happy. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Custom adapter instead of an array adapter.

Good tutorial here: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Is there any other way to do it instead of using a Custom ListAdapter?

Comment: No there isn't. Give that tutorial a go it's very easy to follow.

Comment: Well are you sure this exact code from the tutorial would work with a class that extends SherlockListFragment? Because a lot of other ListView tutorials didn't work with it.

Comment: It should be fine. Give it a go and if you run into any issues let me know.

Comment: Okay I'll give it a go

Comment: The tutorial says that MainActivity.java should extend Activity, which is a problem, because my MainActivity class HAS to extend SherlockListFragment or SherlockFragment or else the app will crash. So I don't think this tutorial will work :/

Comment: Doesn't matter you can extend SherlockListFragment or SherlockFragment, wherever it references activity just use getActivity() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use if listview holds only one string

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = 
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,command);
setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```